# html create a triangle that spans across the page width

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a triangle between two divs in html that span the width of the page (see image below).

[image]

I'm not sure what the css for the arrow_down div should be

```
<div id="top_section" style="width:100%;">
 <div id="arrow_down">
 </div>
</div>
<div id="bottom_section" style="width:100%;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use pseudo element :after

```
#top_section:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 60px #ddd;
    border-left: solid 50vw transparent;
    border-right: solid 50vw transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gb6otzqr/